# "rails server" command not executing on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm in the very first part of building a rails app and I can't get the command

rails server
to work, or really any other rails command. Whenever I attempt a rails command I get the help screen like this:

```
$rails server
Usage:
rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
-r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice                                       # Default: /home/sgallagher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-    p290/bin/ruby
-b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem     path or URL)

-m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
[--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
  [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
-G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
```

nd so on (it gives me the same "rails new" command no matter what command I put in)...

Any ideas on what might be missing in my system or why these commands aren't responding? Thanks

P.S. Another peculiar thing is when I created this app, initially, I used the command:

rails new first_app
This actually created two apps: one called 'new' and another called 'first_app'. It also didn't create a default Gemfile.

I am running Rails 3.1.0 and Ruby 1.9.2. on windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution on more searching
    "bundle install"
command was not executing automatically , i manually run this command , the webrick server started on port 3000 ,

but the problem occuring now is dat every time i started the ROR , i have to execute "bundle install" command to start the server ....... how can i get through this problem ???

Answer (score 2):

firstly try to make your app (e.g. `$rails new app_name`) then `$cd app_name` and finally run `$rails server`

Comment: another error comes up

    C:\Sites\blog>rails server
    ←[31mCould not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sour
ces listed in your Gemfile.←[0m
    ←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

Comment: yes, you are right.. `bundle install` you have to run because of install/update additional gems (or packages) and after that start the server

Comment: how can we automate the  "bundle install" commnad to be execute on making new application i.e. on "rails new project"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change directory in dos or terminal to the proper directory where your rails application is residing...